# How to get the value of url after = sign in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to  get the value in jquery after the equal sign but i am not been able to get the value this is my url

```
https://dev.example.com/front-end-pm/?fepaction=newmessage&=Shammy%20Kothari
```

**this is how i am trying to get the value after the = sign**

```
var url      =window.location.href; 
var queryString = url.split('&', 2)[1] || '';
```

I am getting like this

**=Shammy%20Kothari**

I just Need

Shammy Kothari

Comment: I think, that can by usefully for you http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html?m=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the url using `decodeURIComponent()`

```js
//var url =window.location.href;

var url ="https://dev.example.com/front-end-pm/?fepaction=newmessage&=Shammy%20Kothari";

var str = decodeURIComponent(url.split('=').pop());
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you probably want to change is that the value in your url is not assigned to a name. This would look like this: `https://dev.example.com/front-end-pm/?fepaction=newmessage&YOUR_PARAMETER_NAME=Shammy%20Kothari`
After that you could use URLSearchParams as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript).
This could look like the following:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
//If you don't want to retrieve the url from the url bar just use: const urlParams = new URLSearchParams('https://dev.example.com/front-end-pm/?fepaction=newmessage&YOUR_PARAMETER_NAME=Shammy%20Kothari');
const myParam = urlParams.get('YOUR_PARAMETER_NAME'); //would be 'Shammy Kothari'
```